# Can't update plugins in Wordpress, system returns -1

Tags: plugins, maintenance

We are running Wordpress version 6.1.1. When we try to update one or more (we've tried to do it in several ways) plugins, Wordpress returns a -1 (see image below)

[image: Wordpress returning -1 when trying to update plugins]

The system is then stuck in maintenance mode. We can only get the system out of maintenance mode by deleting the .maintenance file via FTP. Plugins do not update.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that several template plugins are causing these kind of issues (Astra Starter templates, Smart Templates, etc.) If you have one of these installed, try to deactivate them and then update all the plugins, including the template ones. Once updated, you can safely re-active such plugins. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).